# How to change the commit ID of a submodule on remote repo?

Tags: git, git-push

My current submodule has an incorrect commit ID on the remote repo.

How would I do correct it? Simply checkout the commit ID that I want and then push it or I have to delete the submodule from remote repo and push it again with the correct commit ID?

Comment: Just checkout submodule on the correct commit and then commit+push this changes into the parent repo to pin the new pointer to the submodule.